# Near Protocol Access Explorer API

Tags: nearprotocol

How I can access Explorer API so I can fetch some **transaction details**, **block info**, etc...
I check out their github but there must be some endpoints which can allow us to access explorer info easily

Comment: `near-api-js` has the endpoints you are looking for. Although there is an explorer api in the works, it's still labeled as `in development`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://rpc.mainnet.near.org. See here for more details: https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc/contracts

---

Copied from the website:

**Postman Setup​**

An easy way to test the examples below, would be to use an API request tool such as Postman. You will only need to configure two things:

1. Make sure you add a header with a key of `Content-Type` and value of `application/json`:

[image]

2. Then select the Body tab and choose the raw radio button and ensure JSON is the selected format:

[image]

After that is set up, just copy/paste the `JSON object` example snippets below into the body of your request, on Postman, and click send.

E.g. to view an account:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": "dontcare",
  "method": "query",
  "params": {
    "request_type": "view_account",
    "finality": "final",
    "account_id": "nearkat.testnet"
  }
}
```